# Linux booting process

Tags: grub2, filesystem, bootloader

I have some questions regarding the boot process in Linux. So far, I have understood that the BIOS loads the bootstrap code (stage 1 GRUB bootloader) from the boot sector (MBR) to the ram and executes it (the program counter jumps there). In return, the stage 1 bootloader will execute the stage 1.5 bootloader (core.img) that features more functionality. Then, stage 1.5 bootloader will execute the stage 2 GRUB bootloader found in /boot/grub.

So far, the kernel has not been loaded yet. However, stage 1.5 bootloader was able to locate the grub in the /boot directory. Does this mean that the GRUB 1.5 should include the modules to "understand" all the possible filesystems the /boot directory may be located in?

Afterward, the GRUB will load the kernel image in RAM passes the control to it (the kernel).

However, the kernel should not be compiled including all possible modules and functionality as its' size would be increased drastically. However, the kernel loads a temporary initial filesystem  (initrd) in RAM as it is a RAM disk that includes such programs and modules that it can load in demand.
Hence, the kernel SHOULD come with the ability to handle ram disks.

Once it is done, the kernel will move the initrd to another directory and will mount the actual file system at /.

Is my view correct?
Thank you

Comment: Is true that stage1.5 knows all linux filesystems https://www.crybit.com/linux-boot-process/